# Create range name in several files

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a range name in a number of excel files, and then write the file names and paths out to another excel. The files/paths are written correctly, but the range name doesn't appear to be created in the file. Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
Sub directlisting()

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim RangeName As String
Dim CellName As String
Dim i As Integer

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("\\xxxxxxxxxxx\testdata\Transfer")

'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    'open file if an Excel file
    If Right(objFile, 4) = "xls*" Or Right(objFile, 3) = "xl*" Then
        Application.Workbooks.Open (objFile)
        'create range name
        RangeName = "PVS"
        CellName = "A4:AG27"
        Set cell = Worksheets("PVS").Range(CellName)
        objFile.Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersTo:=cell
    'Save the file
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    objFile.Save
    objFile.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

'print file name
Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
'print file path
Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.path
i = i + 1

Next objFile

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Try adding the workbook name you are setting the `cell` to, `..Workbooks("MainBook.xlsx").Worksheets("PVS").Range(cellName)`. It might be grabbing the incorrect range?

Comment: Thanks for replying, BruceWayne. I have over 20,000 excel workbooks, which is why I'm taking this approach. It shouldn't be necessary anyway if it opens the next workbook on each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Does each `objFile` have a sheet called "PVS"? and you're trying to create a named range (named "PVS", range `A4:AG27` in each `objFile`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The Excel files are in 4 different formats - .xls, .xlt, .xlsx, and .xlsm.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and it seemed to work for me.  The main idea was to be more explicit with the workbook/worksheets and what you're calling them on:

```
Sub directlisting()

Dim objFSO As Object, objFolder As Object, objFile As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim RangeName As String, CellName As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim tempWB As Workbook, mainWB As Workbook
Dim mainWS As Worksheet

'Assuming this is running from a "main" workbook
Set mainWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set mainWS = mainWB.ActiveSheet

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("D:\User\Documents\Test") ' CHANGE TO YOUR PATH

'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    'open file if an Excel file
    If Right(objFile, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(objFile, 3) = "xl*" Then
        Set tempWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(objFile)
        'create range name
        RangeName = "PVS"
        CellName = "A4:AG27"
        Set cell = tempWB.Worksheets("PVS").Range(CellName)
        'ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="PVS", RefersToR1C1:="=PVS!R11C8:R18C14"
        tempWB.Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersTo:=cell

        'print file name
        mainWS.Cells(i + 1, 1) = tempWB.Name
        'print file path
        mainWS.Cells(i + 1, 2) = tempWB.Path
        i = i + 1

        'Save the file
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        tempWB.Save
        tempWB.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End If ' Right (objFile, 4) ...

Next objFile

End Sub
```

Small note: I had to change the `... = "xls*" Or Right ...` to `... = "xlsx" Or ...`, because for some reason it wouldn't open the .xlsx file.  Curious.  In any case, let me know if you get any errors or weird issues!

Also, I moved the part where you save the workbook name and path *inside* the `If` statement, so *only* if the file opens, will it mark it.  Just tweak that line if you want to note every file, whether or not it opens.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work for .xlsx and .xls files. When I added `Or Right (ObjFile, 4) = "xlsm"` I get the Security Notice dialog. Is there any way to suppress this? Trust Centre Macro Settings are disabled by my network administrator.

Comment: @RoryWilsher maybe if you disable the alerts before the `Set tempWB = ..` line?